# How to call a function though Control.BeginInvoke in a signal-slot-like fashion?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I'd like a delegate that calls a function in a different thread when it is invoked. Currently, I'm using the following implementation:

```
delegate void someFunctionDelegate();
//...

someFunctionDelegate callBackFunction = someForm.SomeFunction;
someForm.Invoke(someFunctionDelegate);
```

However, I'd like a more compact form, combining both the `someForm` instance and the `SomeForm.SomeFunction` member function. I'm thinking of something like this:

```
var callBackFunction = new AsynchronousCrossThreadDelegate(someForm, SomeForm.SomeFunction);
callBackFunction(); // Should call someForm.BeginInvoke(SomeForm.SomeFunction);
```

Is there a way to do so in C#/.NET?

**Update** I'm looking for a solution that will work for functions with 0 or more parameters.

Answer (score 1):

Would this help?

You'd just do:

```
var callBackFunction = AsynchronousCrossThreadDelegate.Create(someForm, SomeForm.SomeFunction);   
callBackFunction(); // Should call someForm.BeginInvoke(SomeForm.SomeFunction);
```

instead.

```
public class AsynchronousCrossThreadDelegate
{
    public delegate void someFunctionDelegate(); 

    private Control _ctrl;
    private someFunctionDelegate _callback;

    private AsynchronousCrossThreadDelegate( Control ctrl, someFunctionDelegate callback )
    {
        _ctrl = ctrl;
        _callback = callback;
    }

    private void invoke()
    {
        _ctrl.BeginInvoke( _callback );
    }

    public static someFunctionDelegate Create( Control ctrl, someFunctionDelegate callback )
    {
        return (new AsynchronousCrossThreadDelegate( ctrl, callback )).invoke;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I didn't tell in my question, but I'm looking for a solution that will work for functions with 0 or more parameters.

Comment: Since .BeginInvoke just passes an object[] as it's parameter list - maybe you can do the same...? Just asking...? :-)

Comment: Yes, but doesn't "someFunctionDelegate" have to be declared using the full function signature, complete with its parameter list?

Comment: Yes. But you *could* declare it as
public delegate void someFunctionDelegate( params object[] args );
Not saying that you should, though.

Comment: OK, I now understand what you mean. You're right, as Invoke doesn't do parameter type checking, it is useless to try to store it anyway. A disadvantage is that the function to be called back will always require an object[] parameter list. I'll consider whether this drawback doesn't neutralize the advantage of this AsynchronousCrossThreadDelegate class.

Comment: The only other option that I can think of right now would be to write a bunch of generic classes: one for each number of parameters! Actually, that would not be so bad in practice: how often do you have more than, say, five parameters...

Comment: You're right, but I wonder whether C#'s template system is sufficiently powerful for this.

Answer (score 1):

Partly thanks to [my discussion with danbystrom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2689116/how-to-call-a-function-though-control-begininvoke-in-a-signal-slot-like-fashion/2689173#2689173), I found a sufficient solution:

```
public static Action<T> MakeAsyncDelegate<T>(
    this Control form, Action<T> functionToCallAsynchronously)
{
    Action<T> ret = ((T t) => {
        form.BeginInvoke(functionToCallAsynchronously, t);
    });
    return ret;
}
```

This allows you to keep the client code clean:

```
Action<string> signal = form.MakeAsyncDelegate(form.SomeFunction);
signal("some string");
```

Regrettably, the caller has to explicitly specify the template parameter, as the compiler cannot infer it automatically ([see this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/407983/c-3-0-generic-type-inference-passing-a-delegate-as-a-function-parameter)), neither can the compiler check whether the type really matches the function signature (in C++ this can be done).