# Why doesn't the C# compiler automatically infer the types in this code?

Tags: c#, .net, generics, c#-3.0, type-inference

Why does the C# compiler not infer the fact that `FooExt.Multiply()` satisfies the signature of `Functions.Apply()`? I have to specify a separate delegate variable of type `Func<Foo,int,int>` for the code to work ... but it seems like type inference should handle this. Am I wrong? And, if so, why?

EDIT: The compilation error received is:

> *The type arguments for method `FirstClassFunctions.Functions.Apply<T1,T2,TR>(T1, System.Func<T1,T2,TR>, T2)'` cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly*

```
namespace FirstClassFunctions  {
    public class Foo  {
        public int Value { get; set; }

        public int Multiply(int j) {
            return Value*j;
        }
    }

    public static class FooExt  {
        public static int Multiply(Foo foo, int j) {
            return foo.Multiply(j);
        }
    }

    public static class Functions  {
        public static Func<TR> Apply<T1,T2,TR>( this T1 obj, 
                                                Func<T1,T2,TR> f, T2 val ) {
            return () => f(obj, val);
        }
    }


    public class Main  {
        public static void Run()  {
            var x = new Foo {Value = 10};
            // the line below won't compile ...
            var result = x.Apply(FooExt.Multiply, 5);
            // but this will:
            Func<Foo, int, int> f = FooExt.Multiply;
            var result = x.Apply(f, 5);
        }
    }
```

Comment: The following should work as well: `x.Apply(new Func<Foo, int, int>(FooExt.Multiply), 5)`. What's the compile error?

Comment: It seems to compile fine for me, in .NET 4.0.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# 3.0 generic type inference - passing a delegate as a function parameter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/407983/c-3-0-generic-type-inference-passing-a-delegate-as-a-function-parameter)

Comment: Are you sure this is the exact code you're using? You haven't "simplified" it for our benefit?

Comment: @Lasse: I suspect the OP is compiling this in VS2008 - where, if I recall correctly, the C# compiler still had some limitations resolving method groups based on return values.

Comment: So the C# 3.0 compiler in 2010 and 2008 is different? Let me test 2008 as well then. Ah, it's still using the 4.0 compiler, but targetting .NET 3.5.

Comment: Yup, the C# 3.0 compiler doesn't handle this, the 4.0 one does, even when targetting .NET 3.5.

Comment: @Lasse: Yes.  VS 2010 always compiles C#4.0, even when targetting .NET 3.5.  This is more apparent when specifying covariance and contravariance (`in`/`out` generic parameters).

Comment: Even changing the language version in build settings to C#3.0 doesn't break it. Guess this ought to be viewed as a bug in the compiler that has been fixed since.

Answer (score 5):

**I believe this is the result of the VS2008 C# compiler's inability to correctly infer the types involved when converting a method group to a delegate.** @Eric Lippert discusses this behavior in his post [C# 3.0 Return Type Inference Does Not Work On Method Groups](https://web.archive.org/web/20151112002618/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/ericlippert/archive/2007/11/05/c-3-0-return-type-inference-does-not-work-on-member-groups.aspx).

If I recall correctly, some improvements were made in the new C# compiler that's part of VS2010 which expands the cases where method group inference is possible.

Now, the rules for type inference are quite complicated, and I'm far from an expert in this subject. Hopefully someone with some real knowledge can address this question if I am mistaken.

Comment: @Eric Lippert: Thanks for the confirmation. BTW, I thought I recall you blogging about the improvements to type inference in the latest C# compiler, but I can't seem to find any article on your blog to that effect ... perhaps I imagined that.

Comment: I mentioned that we were going to fix it, here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2008/05/28/method-type-inference-changes-part-zero.aspx