# Why does including a named argument cause a "type arguments for method cannot be inferred from usage" error?

Tags: c#, generics, delegates, resharper, named-parameters

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Named arguments and generic type inference in C# 4.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6542822/named-arguments-and-generic-type-inference-in-c-sharp-4-0)

If you attempt to compile this code...

```
public interface IBar { }

public class StandardBar : IBar { }

public class Foo
{
    public TBar GetBarCore<TBar>(Func<TBar> getter)
        where TBar : IBar
    {
        return getter();
    }

    public StandardBar GetBar()
    {
        return GetBarCore(getter: Find);
    }

    public StandardBar Find()
    {
        return new StandardBar();
    }
}
```

...you will get this error:

> The type arguments for method `ConsoleApplication1.Foo.GetBarCore<TBar>(System.Func<TBar>)` cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

It took me a while to figure out that the named argument (`getter:`) on `GetBarCore()` is the culprit. If you remove the argument name, leaving just `GetBarCore(Find)`, the code compiles successfully. Less surprisingly, you can also get the code to compile successfully if, as the error message suggests, you explicitly specify the type argument (resulting in `GetBarCore<StandardBar>(getter: Find)`).

(Incidentally, this little idiosyncrasy tripped up ReSharper as well. I had some code that worked fine. I made a very minor change to the code file and performed a "Cleanup Code" operation, which removes what R# thinks is "redundant" code. Well, it removed one of my seemingly unnecessary explicit type arguments on a method call with a named argument, and suddenly, my code wouldn't compile.)

Can someone explain why providing a named argument would make it impossible for the compiler to infer a type argument from usage?

Comment: @PLB, you're right, my question is pretty much the same. I'm not sure why I didn't come across it in my searches.

Answer (score 2):

Mono's C# compiler (tested with dmcs in Mono 2.10.9) is perfectly happy to infer the type even when using a named parameter. I'm still trying to find something in the standard that indicates one behavior or the other, but I suspect this is just a bug in `csc.exe`.

Also seems to work just fine with `csc.exe` in C# 5.0. (Tested using LINQPad 4.43.06.)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, +1. Turns out, it is a bug. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6542822.