# Why can't these type arguments be inferred?

Tags: c#, .net, generics, type-inference

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C# 3.0 generic type inference - passing a delegate as a function parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/407983/c-3-0-generic-type-inference-passing-a-delegate-as-a-function-parameter)

Why can't the type arguments of the following code sample in the call in `Main` be inferred?

```
using System;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Method(Action);
    }

    static void Action(int arg)
    {
        // ...
    }

    static void Method<T>(Action<T> action)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

This gives the following error message:

> error CS0411: The type arguments for method `Program.Method<T>(System.Action<T>)`
>       cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

Comment: Thank you very much. Searched but I couldn't find it.

Comment: @Pieter: The post mentioned by Darin has the answer, and has some good links to more info.

Comment: Read 10 posts or something, but the above one wasn't among them.

Comment: @Pieter: first hit here: http://www.google.com/#sclient=psy&hl=en&source=hp&q=c%23+infer+delegate+generic&pbx=1&oq=c%23+infer+delegate+generic&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&gs_sm=e&gs_upl=3066l4016l1l4115l8l7l0l0l0l0l214l696l0.3.1l4l0&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.&fp=b7e6040383bebbf&biw=1440&bih=795

Comment: Yep, you're right. I however searched through the suggestions that were presented when asking the question. May'be I'll put a bit more effort in searching the next time :).

Comment: more relevant link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6229131/why-cant-c-sharp-infer-type-from-this-seemingly-simple-obvious-case

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `Action` (aside from already being a type; please rename it) is actually *a method group that is convertible to the delegate type `Action<int>`*. The type-inference engine can't infer the type because method group expressions are *typeless*. If you actually cast the method group to `Action<int>`, then type-inference succeeds:

```
Method((Action<int>)Action); // Legal
```

Answer (score 0):

Just put this is a compiler I see what you mean.

I think it's because `Action` is used as a method group, but it's not of type `Action<int>`.

If you cast it to this type it works:

```
Method((Action<int>)Action);
```

Comment: I would expect it to be int. And I guess the OP already knows what the compiler is telling him.

Comment: Yep until I put it in a compiler I didn't release the context of the problem. Not immediately obvious the Action refers to the method.

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Method<int>(Action);
    }

    static void Action(int arg)
    {
        // ...
    }

    static void Method<T>(Action<T> action)
    {
        // ...
    }
```

Comment: Yes, but that's not what's being asked here. What is asked is why what is shown by the OP **doesn't** work.