# Use Action<object> as method input

Tags: c#

I'm in a case where I would like to have a method that can take other methods as input.

The input method will always have a single object as input, but the objects are different.

This is more or less what i need to be able to do:

```
public static void takeAnything(Action<object> inputFunc)
{
    Console.WriteLine(inputFunc.Method.Name);
}

public static void test1(MyOwnObject input){
    // Do stuff with input object
}

public static void test2(MyOtherOwnObject input){
    // Do stuff with input object
}

public static void startSystem(){
    takeAnything(test1);
    takeAnything(test2);
}
```

Which in this dummy case would write out:

```
test1
test2
```

I just cant't get this to work, so any help would be very much appreciated.

**EDIT**

I do not know if this is possible, maybe it is not, but it is important that the call is just `takeAnything(test1)`, not `takeAnything<MyOwnObject>(test1)` or anything else.

Comment: What exactly is the problem you are having? Have you consindered making `TakeAnything` into a generic method (ie `TakeAnything<T>(Action<T> inputFunc`)?

Comment: I have tried that but I can only get it to work calling it with: takeAnything<MyOwnObject>(test), and if I remove the <MyOwnObject> part i get this error: The type arguments for method 'takeAnything<T>(System.Action<T>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.
I do not know if this is even possible, that is what I hope you guys can help me figuring out :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make your method generic

```
public static void TakeAnything<T>(Action<T> inputFunc)
{
    Console.WriteLine(inputFunc.Method.Name);
}
```

Of course, you will be able only to pass methods which have single input argument.

UPDATE: Unfortunately C# cannot infer action generic parameter type from usage, when you are passing method group to method, so only way to use it is specifying generic parameter type manually

```
takeAnything<MyOwnObject>(test)
```

For details see question [C# 3.0 generic type inference - passing a delegate as a function parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/407983/c-sharp-3-0-generic-type-inference-passing-a-delegate-as-a-function-parameter)

Answer (score 0):

Try this, so you can pass dynamic parameters to action:

```
public static void takeAnything(Expression<Action> inputFunc)
{
    var currentMethod = ((MethodCallExpression)inputFunc.Body);
    Console.WriteLine(currentMethod.Method.Name);
}

public static void test(MyOwnObject input){
    // Do stuff with input object
}

public static void startSystem(){
    MyOwnObject  yourObject = new MyOwnObject();
    takeAnything(() => test(yourObject));
}
```

Comment: -1, did you even try to run this code? How do you think the lambda will be represented in the delegate? No, it won't magically disappear so that `Method.Name` could resolve to `"test"`.

Comment: Seems to work now (with the typo correction that the parameter name in `takeAnything` doesn't match the use in the first line (`action` vs `inputFun`).

Comment: Sorry, I edited my answer. Now I think was correctly

Comment: Thank you for the answer! For the solution I'm working on, all that creating an object and stuff is not good. If it is even possible I would like to be able to just do: takeAnything(test). But maybe it is not possible at all :)

Comment: @Bjarkes To be able to do only `takeAnything(test)`, your action can't have any parameter.

Comment: Removing the -1; however, the drawback of this solution still is one need to supply some (possibly dummy) arguments. I think a reasonable number of overloads with `Action<T1, ..., Tn>` is a slightly better option.

Answer (score -1):

Why not change the header of your `takeAnything` method to:

```
public static void takeAnything(Action<MyOwnObject> inputFunc)
```

Comment: Because the takeAnything method will be called with many different input methods, having different input objects.